# Divide all values in ASCII table (or raster file)

Tags: convert, raster-calculator, arcgis-10.5, raster-conversion, ascii

I have a pile of ASCII files representing 5min radar precipitation sums. The information is given in 1/10 mm which I need to convert into mm for further processing.
Is there a way of doing this, preferably as batch processing since I have more than 100 files? I tried converting the files to raster and use a con statement in the raster calculator (ArcGIS 10.5.1) which would not succeed...

Comment: Are you asking "How to divide a raster by 10?"?

Comment: The answer to most "Is there any way to do this?" questions is "Yes." Please [edit] the question to specify what you have tried and the exact error you received.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I was trying to divide by 10 but had an error in my condition.
Meanwhile I managed to resolve the issue...
In the ArcGIS model builder I used a raster iterator and raster calculator with the correct condition:

```
Con("timestep.tif" > 0, ("timestep.tif" * 0.1), "timestep.tif")
```

Simple now that i wrapped my brain around it! Thank you for your efforts